# Java: checkin whether array have 0 and where;

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building an 2048 in java, and I'm trying to check which places in array are free ( free = which haves 0) in order to pass this free spaces col and row into list . Right now I have a grid like this, and  I need somehow to check all values and find which places are free.

How array looks like:

```
Grid size is 4 x 4
   1   2   3   4   
  ================
 1| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 2| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 3| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 4| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
  ================
```

This Is only what I have for checking right now

```
 public static void addNewNum(int[][]grid) {
        List freeSpace = new ArrayList();
        for(int row=0; row< grid.length; row++)  {
            for(int col=0; col< grid[row].length; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] ==0) {
                    freeSpace.add(col);
                    freeSpace.add(row);
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to create a class which holds a row and column as fields, and create an instance of it to pass to `add` each time you find a free square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must pass the values to a list then you need to define an appropriate class:

```
public final class Coordinate{

    private final int row;
    private final int col;
  
    public Coordinate(final int row, final int col){

        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow(){

        return row;
    }

    public int getCol(){

        return col;
    }
}
```

Then change your list definition to:

```
List<Coordinate> freeSpace = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then to add a free space coordinate:

```
freeSpace.add(new Coordinate(row,col));
```

Thus, your addNewNum method would now look as follows:

```
public static void addNewNum(int[][]grid) {
    List<Coordinate> freeSpace = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int row=0; row< grid.length; row++)  {
        for(int col=0; col< grid[row].length; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] ==0) {
                freeSpace.add(new Coordinate(row,col));
            }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I don't think 2048 involves filling the cells with random numbers.

Comment: I cannot just fill it with random number, I need to just check where is free spaces ( that is why I try to get col and row of free spaces, so latter I could just randomily input number into this free positions

Comment: @RuslanPylypyyuk Ok I've updated my answer. Essentially you just need to make use of a wrapper class. Around the raw coordinate values.

Comment: @RuslanPylypyyuk If my new answer adequately addresses your query then please **accept** it otherwise let me know if you need further clarification on anything.